# Windows Service Use Isolated Storage

Tags: windows, service, storage, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I have a windows service which seems to be unable to use isolated storage (most likely because I'm doing something wrong).
The service is running under local system.
Everytime I run the code there is no change to isolated storage folder.
Can someone please tell me why this is so.
I have tried on windows 7 and windows 8.1

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream configFile = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("UIsolate.cfg", FileMode.Create);

            // create a writer to write to the stream
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(configFile);

            // write some data to the config. file

            writer.WriteLine("test");

            // flush the buffer and clean up
            sr.Close();
            writer.Close();
            configFile.Close();
```

Comment: Is there any real point in using isolated storage in a *service*? It already runs with lots of privileges that allows it to write *anywhere* and is already hard enough to diagnose without hiding its files.  You are surely looking in the wrong directory for the files, the system account uses a profile that is hard to find back.  c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile I think.

Comment: yes, i have to as its an essential task i was told to do

Comment: Well, we didn't tell you to do that.  This site is best for programmers that are allowed to do the right thing, legitimizing bad practices is something that nobody needs.  SO is not a forum.

Comment: I know ye didnt. its part of a college task. I dont have to have the service running under local system. I can change that if someone tells me what to do.